# Rasa run -m models –enable-api –cors“ * ”–debug” not connecting to webchat

Tags: javascript, python, html, chatbot, rasa

I'm facing with the problem is same as this link (https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-run-m-models-enable-api-cors-debug-not-connecting-to-webchat/26728/8)
So help me pleaze

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried so far?